# How to scale/stretch this signal?

Tags: functions

I have a signal (defined by a list of 1000 samples) that take values from -1 to 1.
I need to scale/stretch this. So the values are fixed between 0 and 1, and min/max peaks are **always** 0 a 1 (stretch).

Let say the min peak is -0.469696, and max peak is 0.678888: it become that min peak will be 0 and max peak 1; the rest of samples scaled accordingly to this ratio.

I've tried this:

```
y=0-peak_min + x*((1-(-1))/(peak_max-peak_min))
```

but many values go beyond the threshold. Where am I wrong?

Here's the signal:

```
-0.156146
-0.161158
-0.166004
-0.170649
-0.175053
-0.179181
-0.182996
-0.18646
-0.189536
-0.192273
-0.194727
-0.196873
-0.198684
-0.200135
-0.201198
-0.20185
-0.202062
-0.201864
-0.201291
-0.200331
-0.198972
-0.197201
-0.195005
-0.192372
-0.189289
-0.18576
-0.181799
-0.177407
-0.172588
-0.167342
-0.161673
-0.155581
-0.14907
-0.142118
-0.134716
-0.126878
-0.118623
-0.109967
-0.100927
-0.0915194
-0.0817609
-0.0716082
-0.0610264
-0.0500459
-0.0386968
-0.0270093
-0.0150136
-0.00273989
0.00978166
0.0226143
0.035814
0.0493393
0.0631491
0.0772019
0.0914564
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.0956977
0.531771
0.516854
0.501637
0.486162
0.470349
0.454124
0.437536
0.420637
0.403478
0.386108
0.368579
0.350941
0.333105
0.314983
0.296632
0.278106
0.25946
0.24075
0.22203
0.203357
0.184637
0.165778
0.146837
0.127868
0.108927
0.0900689
0.0713501
0.0528256
0.0344075
0.0160053
-0.0023293
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.0032259
-0.417959
-0.411647
-0.405022
-0.398115
-0.390861
-0.383201
-0.375176
-0.366828
-0.358198
-0.349329
-0.340262
-0.33104
-0.321586
-0.31183
-0.301817
-0.291594
-0.281207
-0.270703
-0.260129
-0.24953
-0.238828
-0.227946
-0.21693
-0.205829
-0.194689
-0.183556
-0.172479
-0.161505
-0.150558
-0.139561
-0.12856
-0.117596
-0.106715
-0.0959609
-0.0853771
-0.0750076
-0.0647871
-0.0546455
-0.0446202
-0.0347484
-0.0250677
-0.0156152
-0.00642834
0.00245549
0.0110875
0.0195251
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.0266052
0.048576
0.0418999
0.0349507
0.0277644
0.0203771
0.0128251
0.00514452
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
-0.000651313
0.0103836
0.0215608
0.0327091
0.043792
0.0548692
0.0660011
0.0771519
0.0882862
0.0993684
0.110363
0.121234
0.131947
0.142556
0.153118
0.163603
0.173977
0.184209
0.194268
0.204121
0.213736
0.22316
0.232442
0.241557
0.250479
0.259183
0.267642
0.275832
0.283725
0.291357
0.298765
0.305933
0.312841
0.319473
0.325812
0.331839
0.337537
0.342924
0.348026
0.352833
0.357338
0.361532
0.365407
0.368953
0.372164
0.375041
0.377594
0.379824
0.381732
0.383319
0.384586
0.385535
0.386165
0.386466
0.386431
0.386069
0.385391
0.384407
0.383126
0.381559
0.379716
0.377571
0.375104
0.372331
0.369272
0.365943
0.362362
0.358548
0.354516
0.350232
0.345663
0.340832
0.335763
0.33048
0.325005
0.319362
0.313575
0.3076
0.301397
0.294993
0.288414
0.281687
0.27484
0.267899
0.260891
0.25377
0.246491
0.239081
0.23157
0.223983
0.21635
0.208699
0.201056
0.193378
0.185619
0.177805
0.169962
0.162117
0.154297
0.146527
0.138835
0.13118
0.123521
0.115879
0.108278
0.100741
0.0932901
0.0859483
0.0787382
0.0716284
0.0645836
0.0576211
0.0507582
0.0440124
0.037401
0.0309413
0.0246507
0.0185079
0.0124873
0.00659963
0.000855734
-0.00473358
-0.0101575
-0.0154052
-0.020466
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0237974
-0.0403776
-0.0397368
-0.0391431
-0.0386037
-0.0381215
-0.0376908
-0.0373055
-0.0369598
-0.0366477
-0.0363633
-0.0361006
-0.0358755
-0.0357007
-0.0355648
-0.0354569
-0.0353658
-0.0352803
-0.0351895
-0.0350821
-0.0349813
-0.0349076
-0.0348459
-0.0347812
-0.0346984
-0.0345825
-0.0344184
-0.034191
-0.033928
-0.0336556
-0.0333565
-0.0330134
-0.0326093
-0.0321268
-0.0315488
-0.030858
-0.0300831
-0.0292529
-0.0283501
-0.0273575
-0.0262578
-0.0250338
-0.0236683
-0.0221439
-0.0204868
-0.0187246
-0.0168423
-0.014825
-0.0126577
-0.0103253
-0.0078131
-0.00510596
-0.0022236
0.000811311
0.00400922
0.00738056
0.0109358
0.0146853
0.0186397
0.0228092
0.0271841
0.0317502
0.0365113
0.0414717
0.0466351
0.0520057
0.0575875
0.0633844
0.069399
0.0756285
0.082069
0.0887167
0.0955678
0.102618
0.109864
0.117302
0.124948
0.132813
0.140885
0.14915
0.157598
0.166214
0.174987
0.183904
0.192996
0.202288
0.211759
0.221388
0.231153
0.241035
0.251012
0.261063
0.271232
0.281557
0.292011
0.302563
0.313187
0.323853
0.334533
0.345197
0.355901
0.366695
0.377545
0.388416
0.399274
0.410083
0.42081
0.431419
0.441974
0.452532
0.463056
0.473507
0.483849
0.494041
0.504047
0.513828
0.523449
0.532973
0.542361
0.551575
0.560576
0.569326
0.577784
0.585913
0.593774
0.601431
0.608848
0.615987
0.622813
0.62929
0.63538
0.641048
0.646348
0.651338
0.655986
0.660262
0.664135
0.667575
0.670552
0.673034
0.675062
0.676684
0.677877
0.678619
0.678888
0.678663
0.67792
0.676639
0.674842
0.672562
0.669786
0.666505
0.662707
0.658381
0.653516
0.648101
0.642139
0.635643
0.628614
0.621054
0.612964
0.604347
0.595203
0.585534
0.575322
0.564558
0.553256
0.541432
0.5291
0.516276
0.502974
0.489209
0.474942
0.46014
0.444832
0.429045
0.412808
0.396149
0.379096
0.361676
0.343829
0.325504
0.306739
0.287574
0.268048
0.248203
0.228076
0.207709
0.187023
0.165948
0.144533
0.122827
0.10088
0.0787394
0.056455
0.0340758
0.0115128
-0.0113189
-0.0343639
-0.057567
-0.080873
-0.104227
-0.127573
-0.150856
-0.174171
-0.197612
-0.22112
-0.244638
-0.268109
-0.291474
-0.314675
-0.337655
-0.360509
-0.383332
-0.406067
-0.428659
-0.45105
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469696
-0.469387
-0.452133
-0.434921
-0.417659
-0.400398
-0.383192
-0.366093
-0.349154
-0.332426
-0.315963
-0.299686
-0.283512
-0.267485
-0.25165
-0.236051
-0.220734
-0.205742
-0.191122
-0.17681
-0.162739
-0.148942
-0.135452
-0.122304
-0.10953
-0.0971635
-0.0852392
-0.0737164
-0.0625461
-0.0517482
-0.0413427
-0.0313497
-0.0217891
-0.012681
-0.00404535
0.00413382
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00597125
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00645705
0.00595909
```

Comment: Can you provide a (very short) segment of sample data the you can reference in your description?

Comment: @EricTowers: I've added the whole signal, so you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried $$y = \frac{x-x_{\text{min}}}{x_{\text{max}} - x_{\text{min}}}$$

Comment: Uhm, it seems to works! What was wrong with my function?

Comment: @markzzz I don't know, I haven't looked too hard at it (all those brackets are difficult to parse) but what this one does is the following: The numerator takes the signal and adds to it so that the minimum is at $0$. Then the denominator scales it so that the maximum is at $1$.